# Windows 7 SNMP Names and OIDs

Tags: windows-7, snmp

I would like to retrieve the list of available SNMP names and/or OIDs for my Windows 7 machine.  Is there a command to do this?  Is there a common list of SNMP names available for Windows?

Currently the names I have are:
cpu
mem
count

Comment: CPU MEM and Count are not OID's. A windows OID will start with '1.3.6.1.4.1.311'. You need to find the microsoft MIBs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There won't be a single list of OIDs/Names for just "Windows"; you'll need a few different ones (some by MS, some by other entities) depending on the machine and options installed.

You could use something like [SNMPWalk](http://www.snmpsoft.com/freetools/snmpwalk.html) to get a full list of all detected OID's.

> SnmpWalk allows you to detect a set of variables that are available for reading on a certain device. You can obtain a full list or just part. By analyzing the results of a network device scan obtained with SnmpWalk you can develop a list of supported MIBs and, in this way, obtain full descriptions of variables and possible values.

Also, once you install the SNMP service, you should get a set of [MIB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Management_information_base)s in `%systemroot%\system32`:

*`DHCP.MIB`*

> Microsoft-defined MIB that contains object types for monitoring the
>   network traffic between remote hosts and DHCP servers

*`HOSTMIB.MIB`*

> Contains object types for monitoring and managing host resources

*`LMMIB2.MIB`*

> Covers workstation and server services

*`MIB_II.MIB`*

> Contains the Management Information Base (MIB-II), which provides a simple, workable architecture and system for managing TCP/IP-based internets

*`WINS.MIB`*

> Microsoft-defined MIB for the Windows Internet Name Service (WINS)

More info from Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379157%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377978%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).